# In an iOS application, where do I store my saved user data?

Tags: ios, filesystems

Where is the appropriate place to stare saved data from users in an iOS application? There doesn't appear to be a particular place, according to the samples and tutorials I've seen.

The Locations sample project uses this path:

```
[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]
```

ButI'm not sure if that's technically an app specific path, or if that's somewhere else in the file system.

Also, I guess I could use a bit of a primer on how the iOS file system works from an App's point of view.

Comment: It depends on the nature of the data. What exactly are you looking to persist to disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is where I'd start.

From the docs:

> The `NSUserDefaults` class provides a programmatic interface for interacting with the defaults system. The defaults system allows an application to customize its behavior to match a user’s preferences. For example, you can allow users to determine what units of measurement your application displays or how often documents are automatically saved. Applications record such preferences by assigning values to a set of parameters in a user’s defaults database. The parameters are referred to as defaults since they’re commonly used to determine an application’s default state at startup or the way it acts by default.

Comment: right! today I am using NSUserDefaults to store!, just one think to keep in mind about NSUserDefaults, you just can persist basic objs, such as NSNumber, NSString ,or structures like, NSDictionary, NSArray!

Comment: @ArthurNeves Not so, you can encode your objects into binary data using [`NSKeyedArchiver`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and then store that anywhere, including `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: @Jabob, awesome!! didnt know about it! will check this out, definitely!

Comment: @Jacob in this case I'm specifically looking for a place to store a .sqlite database.

Comment: @CharlesRandall Oh, well then you'll definitely want to store that in the documents directory.

Comment: @Jacob unless you really need SQLite I would look at using CoreData it's a lot easier to work with and the implementation is a lot easier